# R / Sweave arguments

Tags: r, arguments, sweave

I'm using R and Sweave to generate a report.

> R CMD Sweave MyReport.Rnw

I want to be able to send arguments to the R code because the report is , of course, **"Dynamic"**.So, I would like to be able to do something like this:

> R CMD SWeave MyReport.Rnw PatientId=5

...and have the R code read the `PatientId` value in a variable...

How do I do this? Somebody mentioned using environment variables but that's seems like a non-elegant solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get arguments passed from R command line, you can use the function `commandArgs()`, but unfortunately `R CMD Sweave` does not support extra command line options. However, you can still call Sweave by `R -e`, e.g.

```
R -e "Sweave('MyReport.Rnw')" --args PatientId=1
```

In `MyReport.Rnw`, you do some text processing on `commandArgs(TRUE)`, which gives you a character string `PatientId=1` in this case.

But I believe a better practice is to use the function `Sweave()` in an R script *directly*; e.g. in this case you can write the process in a script like

```
PatientId <- 1
Sweave("MyReport.Rnw")
```

and in `MyReport.Rnw` you use the global variable `PatientId` directly. If you want to generate a series of reports, you can even use a loop for `PatientId`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to 'write' the value where it can be 'read':

- environment variables, as mentioned, are an easy approach with `sys.getenv()`
- configuration or data files you can read
- data base storage

etc pp.  Recall that R code is really *executed* so you can always do a two-step:

```
rScriptOne.r                   # write to foo.txt
R CMD Sweave MyReport.Rnw      # reads from foo.txt
```

Comment: I often frown on using environment variables, which I believe is not a good practice in reproducible research because environment variables are often specific to one single system.

Comment: They are not my favourite either but R for example uses them a metric ton behind the scenes, and does so successfully on difference platforms and systems.