# How to read command line parameter in sweave?

Tags: r, command-line-arguments, sweave

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R / Sweave arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399459/r-sweave-arguments)

I am working on latex and R. I want to read command line parameter in using sweave. I found one example.

[R / Sweave arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399459/r-sweave-arguments/10924564#10924564)

Can someone please post some working example for reading arguments. I am trying

```
R -e "Sweave('MyReport.Rnw')" --args PatientId=1
```

and `commandArgs(TRUE)` in my Rnw file.

```
print(PatientId) 
// Error: chunk 2 Error in print(PatientId) : object 'PatientId' not found Execution halted
```